# Dynamic Visual Studio Debug Arguments

Tags: git, visual-studio, debugging

I have a program which accepts a git branch name as a parameter, so a normal run might look like:

```
    tool.exe --branch My-Feature-Branch
```

When debugging in Visual Studio I'd like it to use the current git branch.

I know I can get the name of the current branch with the command `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`. However, if I use this in the debug command arguments I always get a null value.

Command arguments I've tried:

```
    --branch $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    --branch "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
    --branch (git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)  <- VS complains about rev-parse not being a command
    --branch $(git -C C:/repo/root rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Comment: What *language* (e.g., sh/bash or PowerShell or whatever) is this script written in?

Comment: The tool itself is written in C#, the git command would work in just about any shell scripting language, and I don't know what context Visual Studio evaluates the debug arguments in.

Comment: *I don't know what context Visual Studio evaluates the debug arguments in* That would be the key. If you can't get VS to cooperate, though: instead of running `tool.exe <args>`, run `program-to-run-tool-exe` where the program itself is a script (runnable by VS, in whatever languages allow that) that does the `git rev-parse` part  and other arguments for you.